# How to get consistent positioning for a node with \usebox containing a \tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, boxes

I'm using `beamer` and `tikz` to create an animation of a photon travelling between snowflakes. I have ten `Koch snowflake`s (hence the `\newcommand` in my MWE) typeset with `decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{...`, and subsequently I have many slides within a frame. Since each slide takes about 20 seconds to typeset, I have decided to use `\savebox` and `\usebox` to save time (I tried externalization first, but I rely heavily on external macros, external references, pointers from one `tikzpicture` to another, and therefore gave up). However, I don't know how to match the coordinate systems of the `tikzpicture` inside the `savebox` and the one containing the node where I use the `savebox`.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22950/is-it-possible-to-use-newsavebox-with-more-accurate-bounding-box) appears related, but since my image is off in both coordinates, not only vertically, it appears my issue is a different one.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,spy,fit,positioning,backgrounds,arrows,shapes,intersections,decorations.fractals,decorations.markings,external}
\newcommand{\snowflake}[2]{
    \path[fill,draw] decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ #1 ++(-150:.5*#2/0.866) -- ++(60:#2) -- ++(-60:#2) -- cycle }}}};
}
\newsavebox{\manyflakes}
\savebox{\manyflakes}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={Koch snowflake,amplitude=1pt,segment
length=1pt,start radius=1pt},draw=blue,fill=white,very thin]
\snowflake{(1.81, 1.42)}{0.89}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\usebox{\manyflakes}};
\filldraw[red] (1.81, 1.42) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with photon not centred as desired]

How do I match the coordinate systems of the `savebox` with the one of the `tikzpicture`, so that the circle at `1.81, 1.42` is exactly in the middle of the snowflake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing which is wrong is that you have two spaces, one before and one after the `tikzpicture`, which push the savebox to the right. Note that source file line breaks are turned to spaces (except two in a row which are turned into a `\par`. You need to add a `%` after the opening `{` to remove that space and then one after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Then you should also the `outer sept` to 0pt, which affects the positioning, too.

I also figured that your `\showflake` macro has a bug. It seems that the path starts at `(0,0)` and makes a moveto operation to the start position given by `#1`. This seems to cause the have picture to have a slightly negative X and Y component which pushes the savebox to the upper right. To fix this you can make the `\path` operation already start at `#1`. Then you need to add an empty `\path` which includes `(0,0)`, otherwise TikZ will crop the image to only contain the flake, but not the origin.

The following code gives me a perfect match. I added a second circle for easy comparison.

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,spy,fit,positioning,backgrounds,arrows,shapes,intersections,decorations.fractals,decorations.markings,external}
\newcommand{\snowflake}[2]{%
    \path (0,0);
    \path[fill,draw] #1 decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ #1 ++(-150:.5*#2/0.866) -- ++(60:#2) -- ++(-60:#2) -- cycle }}}};
}
\newsavebox{\manyflakes}
\savebox{\manyflakes}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={Koch snowflake,amplitude=1pt,segment
        length=1pt,start radius=1pt},draw=blue,fill=white,very thin]
        \snowflake{(1, 2)}{0.89}
        \filldraw[green] (1, 2) circle [radius=0.11];% For comparison
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\usebox{\manyflakes}};
\filldraw[red] (1, 2) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @gerrit: Please have a look at my updated answer. There was an hidden issue I fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! That was not even part of question :)

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `anchor=south west` option and use the `overlay` and `remember picture` options; there were also a pair of spurious blank spaces which I removed in my example code (one after `\savebox{\manyflakes}{` and the other one at the end after `\end{tikzpicture}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,spy,fit,positioning,backgrounds,arrows,shapes,intersections,decorations.fractals,decorations.markings,external}

\newcommand{\snowflake}[2]{
    \path[fill,draw] decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ #1 ++(-150:.5*#2/0.866) -- ++(60:#2) -- ++(-60:#2) -- cycle }}}};
}
\newsavebox{\manyflakes}
\savebox{\manyflakes}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,decoration={Koch snowflake,amplitude=1pt,segment
length=1pt,start radius=1pt},draw=blue,fill=white,very thin]
\snowflake{(1.81, 1.42)}{0.89}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\usebox{\manyflakes}};
  \filldraw[red] (1.81, 1.42) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to accept both answers! I finally chose Martins because I find it a bit cleaner and it explains why my current one goes wrong.

Comment: @gerrit Yes, it's better to accept his answer. I'll delete mine.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: No need to delete yours (I took the liberty to undelete it). Using `overlay` here is a good idea, because it avoids issues with the bounding box (because there is none then). Using `remember picture` however, might not work with saveboxes. Anyway, AFAIK it is only needed if you want to address included nodes by name. (But I'm aware that in them majority of cases this both options are used together.)