# How can I draw a TikZ element multiple times against a shaded background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

If I have two tikzpictures drawn:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{treetop/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},decorate},trunk/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},decorate}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
\fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
}
\foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
   \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I use the first tikz picture within the second? Can I define the first picture as some variable and then place this variable within the second picture and have the option of defining its exact location (x,y) and its size? For example, if I wanted to place the tree in the middle of the rectangle (5,5) but make the size of the tree half its current size. How would I do this

Comment: Can it be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37823/how-to-get-consistent-positioning-for-a-node-with-usebox-containing-a-tikzpict

Comment: How about using the background canvas via ´\begin{scope}[background] ... \end{scope}´ for the second image?  (I am still a beginner.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would define a specific key for the tree and one for the position:

```
% to get the positions of last x,y
\newdimen\xval
\newdimen\yval

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
   at/.initial={(0,0)},
   at/.get=\coordpos,
   at/.store in=\coordpos,   
   my tree/.code={
     \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
       \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] \coordpos ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
     }
     \pgfgetlastxy{\xval}{\yval};
     \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
       \fill [green!\f!black, treetop](\xval,\yval) ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
     }
   }
}
```

so that in the final picture you can use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\node[at={(2.5,5)},my tree]{};
\node[at={(5,5)},my tree]{};
\node[at={(7.5,5)},my tree]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{treetop/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},decorate},trunk/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},decorate}}

% to get the positions of last x,y
\newdimen\xval
\newdimen\yval

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
   at/.initial={(0,0)},
   at/.get=\coordpos,
   at/.store in=\coordpos,   
   my tree/.code={
     \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
       \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] \coordpos ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
     }
     \pgfgetlastxy{\xval}{\yval};
     \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
       \fill [green!\f!black, treetop](\xval,\yval) ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
     }
   }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\node[at={(2.5,5)},my tree]{};
\node[at={(5,5)},my tree]{};
\node[at={(7.5,5)},my tree]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: +1 Much more elegant solution than mine. I need to get up to speed on `pgfkeys`!

Comment: @Jubobs: definitely ;)

Comment: +100 This is brilliant. You just helped me save hundreds of lines of code as I had lots of variations on the same image throughout a document. I don't know if it's correct or not, but specifying coordinates within a node works as well.

Answer (score 42):

[`TiKZ 3.0.0`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) introduces `pic` a "short picture" which can be inserted in any place of a `tikzpicture`. A possible solution with 'pic' would be:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{treetop/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},decorate},trunk/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},decorate}}

\tikzset{
   my tree/.pic={
     \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
       \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,3);
     }
     \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
       \fill [green!\f!black, treetop](0,3) ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
     }
   }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\pic at (2,2) {my tree};
\pic at (4,2.5) {my tree};
\pic at (6,1.75) {my tree};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You deserve more upvotes. This is the most elegant variant.

Comment: Is there anyway of adding a parameter to control features, such as the size?

Comment: @mattdns you can try with `\pic[scale=0.8] at (...) {my tree};`

Answer (score 6):

Let us define a `newcommand`:

```
\newcommand\myfig[2]{%
    \begin{scope}[xshift=#1cm,yshift=#2cm]
        \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {%
            \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
            }
        \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {%
            \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
            }
    \end{scope}
}
```

And use it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}

\newcommand\myfig[2]{%
    \begin{scope}[xshift=#1cm,yshift=#2cm]
        \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {%
            \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
            }
        \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {%
            \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
            }
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{treetop/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},decorate},trunk/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},decorate}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \myfig{0}{0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
    \myfig{2.5}{5}
    \myfig{5}{5}
    \myfig{7.5}{5}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think, this is very elegant, too.   And---just in case---it solved my actual problem very well!  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it can be done with a `pgfonlayer` environment within the `tikzpicture` and a new command (called `\treedrawing` below) that takes as argument the coordinates (of the form `x,y`)  of the tree and draws it there. Just make sure to call `\treedrawing` *after* the `pgfonlayer` environment, or your trees will be behind the background.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    backgrounds,%
    decorations.pathmorphing,%
    calc,%
    shapes,%
    shapes.geometric,%
    patterns,%
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\treedrawing[1]{%
    \tikzset{%
        treetop/.style = {decoration    = {random steps, segment length=0.4mm},decorate},%
        trunk/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},decorate}%
    }
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
    \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70}{%
        \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
    }
    \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90}{%
        \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
    }
\end{scope}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \treedrawing{2,5}
    \treedrawing{5,5}
    \treedrawing{8,5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```