# How could I make overlapping drawings with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a big drawing with several mini-drawings overlap each other in it. How could I do this with TikZ? If I try it, you still see every line of every drawing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You might want to have a look to [How can I draw a TikZ element multiple times against a shaded background?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126161/13304).

Comment: Assuming you composed the mini-drawings independently and now want merge them, and that they use different coordinates, you can put each inside a scope using \begin{scope}[xshift=??,yshift=??] for some xshift and yshift values.  If you have one drawing and want to create multiple blow-ups, look into clipping rectangles.