# Why styles aren't propagated in TikZ scopes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to embed a (complex) TikZ picture in a command in order to reuse it in several scales and colors. No problems when scaling, but I cannot change the color of the image (see image below for MWE output).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{mystyle/.style={fill=#1}, mystyle/.default=black}

\newcommand{\aaa}{
  \begin{scope}
    \path[mystyle] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
}
\newcommand{\bbb}{
  \begin{scope}[mystyle=blue]
    \path[mystyle] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    Black triangle:&
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \aaa
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    Red triangle:&
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle=red]
      \aaa
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    Red triangle:&
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}[mystyle=red]
        \aaa
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    Blue triangle:&
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \bbb
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    Red triangle:&
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle=red]
      \bbb
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    Red triangle:&
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}[mystyle=red]
        \bbb
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE rendering]

Comment: I don't really understand why you expect a different outcode. Your path is doing [mystyle] which is equivalent to [mystyle=black].

Comment: Try with `\newcommand{aaa}[1][black]{\begin{scope}\path[mystyle=#1](0,0)...\end{scope}}`. Then `\aaa` or `\aaa[red]`, ...

Comment: `mystyle/.default=black` says 'whenever `mystyle` is called with no argument, use `black`'. So you set `mystyle=blue` for the scope, but then you override that value with `mystyle`=`mystyle=black` for the `\path`.

Comment: In addition to the other comments and answers, you might want to create a `pic` ?

Answer (score 1):

As cfr and Ulrike explained, `\path[mystyle]` is equivalent to the default style: `\path[mystyle=black]`. Then, although you use `\begin{scope}[mystyle=red]` it has no effect because `\path[mystyle]` overwrites it.

In case you want all `path` in each `scope` use the same style you can use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={mystyle=red}]
\path (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another solution is what I've proposed in my comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{mystyle/.style={fill=#1}, mystyle/.default=black}

\newcommand{\aaa}[1][black]{
  \begin{scope}
    \path[mystyle=#1] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    Black triangle:& \tikz{\aaa}\\
    Red triangle:& \tikz{\aaa[red]}\\
    Blue triangle:& \tikz{\aaa[blue]}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Note: Although I don't recommend and as a collateral effect of this declaration you can even say `\aaa[blue, scale=-1, draw=red, ultra thick]` to obtain

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that in the scope there is more than one path, so I cannot say `every path`, neither I can define commands for all the parts. I'll try a workaround with a `\def` or something like that.

Comment: @Astrinus I understand you cannot use `every path`, that's why I suggested `\aaa[...]`. But if you give us more details about your problem it will be easier for us to help you. Complex figures can be defined inside a `tikzpicture` but TiKZ also provides command `pic` for reusing parts of a tikzpicture: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151772/1952

Comment: I have a logo, with three colors and several filled area (about 10). This logo is currently embedded in a scope in order to embed it in different ways with a single command. Now a sheet with many logos, each with slighty different colors from its neighbour, has to be generated and I thought that `\foreach` would help me a lot. The colors are already styled in the same way as above.

Comment: @Astrinus   Although this description is a little bit better I still don't understand the problem. Could you show the code? Or at least something more similar to your real problem than your original question?

Comment: Something similar would involve two paths and two styles, or ten paths and three styles, but the same principle of `\aaa` holds: I have a command that holds the content of a scope and the path are styled in that way

Comment: I have resolved using `\colorlet` and overwriting colors. Sledgehammer way, but it works ;-)