# Tikz macro with calculation error

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, calculations

I'm very new to this so bare with me. To get the hang of macros I wanted to write a simple command to draw a square in tikz. Now I know there are a lot of ways to do this, but I want to be able to write more difficult macros.

My code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\tikzsquare}[2]{
    \fill[blue!40!white, opacity=0.5] (#1, #2) rectangle (#1 + 2, #2 + 2);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (4,4);
    \tikzsquare{0,0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What I would have expected was something like this:

[image: expected]

Instead I got this error:

```
...
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.14 \end
         {tikzpicture}
?
Runaway argument?
{pgfstrokecolor}{)}\ifx \reserved@a \@currenvir \else \@badend {)}\fi \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \XC@definec@lor was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.14 \end
         {tikzpicture}
?

! LaTeX Error: \begin{tikzpicture} on input line 11 ended by \end{+}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.14 \end
         {tikzpicture}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Instead of `\tikzsquare{0,0}` you should use `\tikzsquare{0}{0}`. Every parameter in its own pair of braces.

Comment: Instead of `commands` I'd suggest using `pics` for more complex macros. Examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/how-can-i-draw-a-tikz-element-multiple-times-against-a-shaded-background/151772#151772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have told LaTeX that `\tikzsquare` has *two* arguments, but have only given it *one* (`0,0`), so `\end` is being grabbed as `#2` and all sorts of weirdness results. You want `\tikzsquare{0}{0}`.

(More generally, note that TeX arguments are *not* comma-separated, but must be given in separate brace groups.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want you could define

```
\def\tikzsquare(#1,#2);{\fill[blue!40!white,opacity=0.5] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+2,#2+2);}
```

and then use `\tikzsquare(0,0);` which has more TikZ-ish syntax.