# Coordinates within a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a document with multiple variations on what is essentially the same image, and using [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/how-can-i-draw-a-tikz-element-multiple-times-against-a-shaded-background/151772#151772), I was able to simplify things a lot.

When I draw pictures, I usually use *many* coodinates to aid in connecting various parts together. I've just noticed that coordinates specified within a node seem to be accessible outside it, which is really helpful for my drawing style, but I'm left wondering if this is an expected feature of TikZ, or a useful trick that is asking for difficult-to-debug troubles. I'm really hoping for the former, as this technique makes drawing really simple.

Here's an **MWE** to illustrate what I mean. I've removed all the packages and code that aren't required though the drawing itself is still fairly complex as I wanted to illustrate the number of named nodes and coordinates within the pic that are accessible wherever it is placed (provided there isn't a name clash).

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all, per-mode=symbol}
\DeclareSIPostPower\fourth{4}


\tikzset{%
  % End view, "real" x-axis points directly out of page. Projects end view of
  % view top left/right systems
  view end yz/.style={ 
    x={(0cm,1cm)},     % Simulated y-axis (actually x-axis)
    y={(1cm,0cm)},    % Simulated z-axis (actually y-axis)
  },
  dim edge/.style={densely dashed, line width=0.5pt, shorten >= -2.5mm, color=black!75!white},
  dim length/.style={draw, line width=0.5pt, arrows={Stealth-Stealth}, every node/.style={anchor=mid, midway, fill=white, node font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  cross section/.pic={
    \path
      (0.1, 0) coordinate (bottom-left)
      -- ++(0, 1.5) coordinate (bottom-right)
      -- ++(1.5, 0) coordinate (top-right)
      -- ++(0, -1.5) coordinate (top-left)
      -- cycle;

    \fill[draw]
      (top-left)
      -- (top-right)
      -- ++(0.1, 0) coordinate (flange-top-right)
      -- ($(top-left) + (0.1, 0)$) coordinate (flange-top-left)
      -- (top-left)
      -- cycle
      (bottom-left)
      -- ++(-0.1, 0) coordinate (flange-bottom-left)
      -- ++(0, 0.5) coordinate (flange-bottom-inner-left)
      -- ++(0.1, 0) coordinate (flange-top-inner-left)
      -- cycle
      (bottom-right)
      -- ++(-0.1, 0) coordinate (flange-bottom-right)
      -- ++(0, -0.5) coordinate (flange-bottom-inner-right)
      -- ++(0.1, 0) coordinate (flange-top-inner-right)
      -- cycle;

    \fill[draw]
      ($(bottom-left)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-left) - (0, 0.03)$) coordinate (left-web-bottom-left)
      -- ($(bottom-left)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-left) + (1.5, -0.03)$) coordinate (left-web-top-left)
      -- ($(bottom-left)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-left) + (1.5, 0.03)$) coordinate (left-web-top-right)
      -- ($(bottom-left)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-left) + (0, 0.03)$) coordinate (left-web-bottom-right)
      -- cycle
      ($(bottom-right)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-right) - (0, 0.03)$) coordinate (right-web-bottom-left)
      -- ($(bottom-right)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-right) + (1.5, -0.03)$) coordinate (right-web-top-left)
      -- ($(bottom-right)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-right) + (1.5, 0.03)$) coordinate (right-web-top-right)
      -- ($(bottom-right)!0.5!(flange-top-inner-right) + (0, 0.03)$) coordinate (right-web-bottom-right)
      -- cycle;

  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{scope}[view end yz, name prefix=end-]
    \fill[blue!60!white, draw=blue]
      (0.1, 0) coordinate (bottom-left)
      -- ++(0, 1.5) coordinate (bottom-right)
      -- ++(1.5, 0) coordinate (top-right)
      -- ++(0, -1.5) coordinate (top-left)
      -- cycle;

    \pic[fill=blue!40!white, draw=blue] at (0, 0){cross section};

    \draw[dim edge] (flange-bottom-left) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-left-flange-left);
    \draw[dim edge] (flange-bottom-inner-left) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-left-flange-inner);
    \draw[dim edge] (flange-bottom-inner-right) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-right-flange-inner);
    \draw[dim edge] (flange-bottom-right) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-right-flange-right);

    \draw[dim edge] (flange-top-left) -- ++(0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-top-flange-left);
    \draw[dim edge] (flange-top-right) -- ++(0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-top-flange-right);

    \draw[dim length] (dim-left-flange-left) -- (dim-left-flange-inner) node[below=0.1] {\SI{25}{\mm}};
    \draw[dim length] (dim-right-flange-right) -- (dim-right-flange-inner) node[below=0.1] {\SI{25}{\mm}};

    \draw[dim length] (dim-top-flange-left) -- (dim-top-flange-right) node[above=0.1] {\SI{75}{\mm}};

  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm, view end yz, name prefix=centre-]

    \pic[fill=blue!40!white, draw=blue] at (0, 0){cross section};

    \draw[dim edge] ($(left-web-bottom-left) - (0.1, 0)$) -- ++(-0.5, 0) coordinate (dim-left-web-left);
    \draw[dim edge] ($(left-web-bottom-right) - (0.1, 0)$) -- ++(-0.5, 0) coordinate (dim-left-web-right);
    \draw[dim edge] ($(right-web-bottom-left) - (0.1, 0)$) -- ++(-0.5, 0) coordinate (dim-right-web-left);
    \draw[dim edge] ($(right-web-bottom-right) - (0.1, 0)$) -- ++(-0.5, 0) coordinate (dim-right-web-right);

    \draw[dim length, arrows={Stealth-}] (dim-left-web-left) -- ++(0, -0.25);
    \draw[dim length, arrows={Stealth-}] (dim-right-web-right) -- ++(0, 0.25);
    \draw[dim length] (dim-left-web-right) -- (dim-right-web-left) node[above=0.1] {\SI{47}{\mm}};
    \draw[dim length, draw=none] (dim-left-web-left) -- (dim-left-web-right) node[below=0.1] {\SI{3}{\mm}};
    \draw[dim length, draw=none] (dim-right-web-left) -- (dim-right-web-right) node[below=0.1] {\SI{3}{\mm}};

  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[yshift=3cm, view end yz, transform shape, scale=2, name prefix=big-]
    \fill[red!60!white, draw=red]
      (0.1, 0) coordinate (bottom-left)
      -- ++(0, 1.5) coordinate (bottom-right)
      -- ++(1.5, 0) coordinate (top-right)
      -- ++(0, -1.5) coordinate (top-left)
      -- cycle;

    \pic[fill=red!40!white, draw=red] at (0, 0){cross section};

  \end{scope}

  \draw[dim edge] (big-flange-bottom-left) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-flange-bottom-left);
  \draw[dim edge] (big-bottom-left) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-web-bottom);
  \draw[dim edge] (big-top-left) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-web-top);
  \draw[dim edge] (big-flange-top-left) -- ++(-0.25, 0) coordinate (dim-flange-top-left);

  \draw[dim length] (dim-web-bottom) -- (dim-web-top) node[left=0.1] {\SI{75}{\mm}};
  \draw[dim length, arrows={Stealth-}] (dim-flange-bottom-left) -- ++(0, -0.25);
  \draw[dim length, arrows={Stealth-}] (dim-flange-top-left) -- ++(0, 0.25);
  \draw[dim length, draw=none] (dim-flange-bottom-left) -- (dim-web-bottom) node[left=0.1] {\SI{5}{\mm}};
  \draw[dim length, draw=none] (dim-web-top) -- (dim-flange-top-left) node[left=0.1] {\SI{5}{\mm}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also works if I define the repeated picture as a `pic`, and I think that method is more "correct". Using `pic`s also allows me to set colours and styles to the resulting object, but as far as I can tell, *only* if the object contains a single fill and colour.

Comment: You know that the M in MWE stands for minimal?

Comment: Yes, but I was illustrating the point with a complex example, and it's much quicker to copy and paste a part of the document I'm working on than to come up with a much simpler example. It still works, and it's mostly a matter of copying and pasting the code; I stripped out everything I didn't think it needed to work.

Comment: Well it may be much quicker for you. But it is obvious that it will take to much of *my* time to wade through your code only to understand your question. So I will leave and answer something else.

Comment: I'm with @UlrikeFischer. Life's too short to figure out what you mean. Which coordinate? Which node? And does the trick really depend on `fontspec` and `physics`? If so, then I'd say that it is not at all safe to rely on it, no.

Comment: How minimal a MWE should I provide? I used an example with lots of coordinates to illustrate that all the coordinates specified within the `pic` are accessible outside of it, which is unexpected but (if it's a bug) actually a really useful feature.

Comment: It is not a bug and it is not unexpected. Read the paragraph »Name scopes.«  in section »The Pic Syntax« on page 254 of the current documentation (version 3.0.1a).

Comment: Where are the problem to solve and the question?

Comment: @esdd Ah thanks. I should really thoroughly read manuals rather than just skim through to find out whatever I'm looking for at the time.

Comment: @esdd That part of the manual is indirectly relevant. However, referring to it without mentioning that the behaviour described there is currently completely broken is rather misleading. I wouldn't count on *anything* to do with referring to nodes or coordinates in `pic`s continuing to work indefinitely because I have no idea what the fix for this is going to look like if it ever comes. `pic`s are buggy as currently implemented. Period. They mostly work. They sometimes fail spectacularly. Try, for example, the `seagull` example from the manual.

Comment: Referencing points within the pic from outside is one part which is currently especially broken. It used to work. It hasn't worked for ages.