# tikz \savebox only showing part of image

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I can't get tikz to show the whole image created by using \showbox. I think it is a node issue and have tried using a scope and using local bounding box but that doesn't work either. I have posted the code below as well.

For the record I started using the answers provided in the following post to get to where I am now. [How to get consistent positioning for a node with \usebox containing a \tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37823/how-to-get-consistent-positioning-for-a-node-with-usebox-containing-a-tikzpict).

For the record I am attempting to do this because I need to use the image on a chain, but draw different lines on top of it as well. but first need to be able to repeat this multiple times. Plus I may be using this same image in other tikz pictures/drawings as well.

## CODE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
% Helpful resources
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37823/how-to-get-consistent-positioning-for-a-node-with-usebox-containing-a-tikzpict

% general packages or settings

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,arrows,scopes,shapes,chains,matrix,fit,quotes,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,patterns,shadings}



\tikzset{
    %general shapes
    unburn/.style={circle, draw=black,minimum size=0.2cm},
    burn/.style={circle, draw=black,minimum size=0.2cm,pattern=crosshatch},
    burning/.style={circle, draw=black,minimum size=0.2cm,pattern=dots},
    every join/.style={-latex}
}


%custom nodes
\newcommand{\chamber}[1]{

    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
        %draw combustion chamber
        %outer coordinates of chamber
        \coordinate (p1) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (p2) at (0,4);
        \coordinate (p3) at ($(p2)+(30:2)$);
        \coordinate (p4) at ($(p3)+(2,0)$);
        \coordinate (p5) at ($(p4)+(-30:2)$);
        \coordinate (p6) at ($(p5)+(0,-4)$);
        
        %additional coordinates for reference
        \coordinate (p7) at ($(p1)!0.5!(p6)$); %middle point at the bottom of the chamber
        \coordinate (p8) at ($(p3)!0.5!(p4)$); %middle point at top of chamber
        
        %draw cylinder
        \draw[very thick] (p1)--(p2)--(p3)--(p4)--(p5)--(p6);
        %draw piston
        \filldraw[fill=gray!60,very thick] (p1)+(0.2,0) rectangle ++($(p6)+(-0.2,1.8)$);
        \filldraw[fill=white,very thick] ($(p7)+(0,0.9)$) circle (0.26);
        
        %draw spark plug
        \filldraw[fill=gray!60] ($(p8)+(-0.12,-0.8)$) rectangle ($(p8)+(0.12,0)$);
        \filldraw[fill=gray!60] ($(p8)+(-0.06,-0.8)$) rectangle ($(p8)+(0.06,-1)$);
        \draw[semithick] ($(p8)+(0.18,0)$) |- ($(p8)+(-0.12,-1.08)$);
        
        
  \end{scope}
}
\newsavebox{\manychamber}
\savebox{\manychamber}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \chamber{};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    

}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[start chain=going below]
        \pgfmathsetseed{4} %get same random decorations repeated
        \def\ht{4}; %total height of chamber
        \def\cmtopt{28.45274} %cm to pt conversion
        \node at (0,0){\usebox{\manychamber}};

        %\draw[help lines,step=0.05cm,opacity=0.2] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);

    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the following line:

```
\def\ht{4}; %total height of chamber
```

The command `\ht` is an important TeX command for the height of a box. It is used in various places in LaTeX and TikZ.

To detect this kind of accident, LaTeX provides `\newcommand`. The equivalent line with `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand*{\ht}{4}
```

And LaTeX detects the accident and raises an error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \ht already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

PS:
The star form `\newcommand*` uses `\def`, `\newcommand` without star uses `\long\def` and allows arguments with paragraphs (`\par` tokens/empty lines). Since the macro does not have arguments, the difference does not matter here.